# Database request

Tags: sql, database, request

I am want to do the following request to my database:

I am looking for persons who worked togehter with another person as actor (job) in min 10 movies. Do you have any hints or suggestions, how I could solve this problem?

- PRODUCTION (production, title)
- MOVIE (production -> PRODUCTION, type)
- PERSON (person, name, realname, birth_country) WORKS (person ->
- PERSON, production -> PRODUCTION, job)

Comment: Hi Kahoona, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the sort of question better suited to a graph database like Neo4j but here is a relational SQL solution:

```
select w1.person as person1
       , w2.person as person2
       , count(w1.production) as joint_productions
 from works w1
     join works w2
          on w1.production = w2.production
 where w1.person != w2.person
 group by w1.person, w2.person having count(w1.production) >= 10
 order by w1.person, w2.person;
```

This shows both actors and the number of movies they've been in together. It includes the reciprocals, that is

```
 bill murray, dan ackroyd, 10
 dan ackroyd, bill murray, 10
```

If you just want a set of names you could do this:

```
 select distinct w1.person 
 from works w1
     join works w2
          on w1.production = w2.production
 where w1.person != w2.person
 group by w1.person, w2.person having count(w1.production) >= 10
 order by w1.person;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly reply. "person" is only the ID of a person. I want to show their realnames. There I have to join also the persons table right? Would it be possible to use your code as a sub-request and to join the persons table in the main request?

Answer (score 0):

I probably find a solution without a subrequest. Is it correct?

```
select w1.person as person1, w2.person as person2, p1.name , p2.name, count(w1.production) as joint_productions
from works w1 join works w2 on w1.production = w2.production
join person p1 on w1.person = p1.person
join person p2 on w2.person = p2.person
where w1.person != w2.person
group by w1.person, p1.name, p2.name, w2.person having count(w1.production)
>= 10 order by w1.person, w2.person
```